# Swap 2 characters in strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column which contains strings like this:

```
ABCDEFG
ACDEF
ACDEFG
ACFG
ACDEFG
```

I would like to swap 2 character in a number of strings contain those characters. The rows are chosen randomly. For example, I need to swap A and C in 3 rows ( the rows are chosen randomly ). The expected output is:

```
CBADEFG
CADEF
ACDEFG
ACFG
CADEFG
```

Comment: Do you have more than 1 A and 1 C - i.e. do you need to limit the replacement to single swap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA approach that:

- randomises the row selection (50/50)
- checks both the "A" and "C" characters exist pre-swap
- swap first occurrence only

  [image]

*code*

```
Sub ACDC()
Randomize
Dim X
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim strIn As String
Dim strOut As String

strIn = "A"
strOut = "C"
X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
    If Rnd() > 0.5 Then
    'check for both conditions
        If InStr(X(lngCnt, 1), strIn) Then
            If InStr(X(lngCnt, 1), strOut) Then
                X(lngCnt, 1) = Replace(X(lngCnt, 1), strIn, "|", , 1)
                X(lngCnt, 1) = Replace(X(lngCnt, 1), strOut, strIn, , 1)
                X(lngCnt, 1) = Replace(X(lngCnt, 1), "|", strOut, , 1)
            End If
        End If
     End If
Next

[b1].Resize(lngCnt - 1, 1).Value2 = X

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to swap a percentage of records instead of just swap 2 rows ? Let say we want to swap A and C in 20% of the records which contain A and C randomly.

Comment: @kgk replace `If Rnd() > 0.5 Then` with `If Rnd() > 0.8 Then`

Comment: I do note my code above should replaces 50% of rows (when run many times). For a single run, on 5 cells, it is probable 2 or 3 will be updated (although 0 and 5 are possible, but unlikely)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your strings are in A2:A6 and row number criteria are in E1:G1, then try this...

In B2

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROWS(A$2:A2),$E$1:$G$1,0)),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"C","^"),"A","C"),"^","A"),A2)
```

and copy it down.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought if it would be helpful for anyone.

In Excel formula, try something like this,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"A","|"),"C","A"),"|","C").
```

In VBA, try something like this,

```
strSwap = Replace(Replace(Replace(strToSwap, "A", "|"), "C", "A"), "|", "C")
```